# Mercurial fails with missing attribute using Python 2 instead of Python 3

Tags: python, mercurial

I'm working on a multiuser system with mercurial. I haven't been using the system lately, and today I wanted to start again, but mercurial refuses to work:

```
$ hg help
*** failed to import extension transplant from
mercurial_keyring =: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\nmercurial_keyring ='
** Unknown exception encountered with possibly-broken third-party extension hgflow
** which supports versions unknown of Mercurial.
** Please disable hgflow and try your action again.
** If that fixes the bug please report it to the extension author.
** Python 2.7.10 (default, May 26 2015, 04:16:29) [GCC 5.1.0]
** Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 3.4)
** Extensions loaded: color, largefiles, graphlog, hgk, strip, mq, rebase, record, shelve, hgflow, terse-status
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/hg", line 43, in <module>
    mercurial.dispatch.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 29, in run
    sys.exit((dispatch(request(sys.argv[1:])) or 0) & 255)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 91, in dispatch
    ret = _runcatch(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 160, in _runcatch
    return _dispatch(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 746, in _dispatch
    extensions.loadall(lui)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/extensions.py", line 123, in loadall
    extsetup(ui)
  File "/home/UNISIEGEN/gk784/.hg/terse-status/terse-status.py", line 40, in extsetup
    '_poststatus', _poststatus)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/extensions.py", line 255, in wrapfunction
    origfn = getattr(container, funcname)
AttributeError: type object 'workingctx' has no attribute '_poststatus'
```

Mercurial works for all other users. My first observation was the usage of Python 2.7 instead of the default Python 3.4:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.4.3
```

Also removing the module from the global hgrc doesn't help. Then the error occurs for another module:

```
$ hg parent
** Unknown exception encountered with possibly-broken third-party extension hgflow
```

Same error message, same callstack.

Nothing in my env looks suspicious, there are no modules loaded, so I'm a little bit puzzled now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that it is due to the now incompatible extension [terse-status](https://bitbucket.org/mg/terse-status).